# Delete specific files within a directory. How can i do it?

Tags: programming, files-and-directories

I'm a teacher and I have a lot of files (hundreds) with different names in different directories *for example "religion guide.docx","natural sciences guide.pdf" ,"Algebra 2 Guide.pdf".
I intend to leave only the math and physics and delete the rest but in batches, how do I make MMA allow me to choose the directory with which I want to operate and make a database with keywords of things that I want to delete something like,this is a possible example:
$Delete [ *religion*.* , *naturales*.* etc]$
Hope it's understandable

Comment: I strongly recommend saving your files in a different folder before experimenting with deleting files in Mathematica. From what I understood you need `FileNames` and `DeleteFile`. From the documentation of those functions it is kind of straight forward,

Comment: But as would be the structure of the program that does the deletion, I am a beginner in MMA. I have seen several posts but I have not seen one with these requirements

Comment: There is not much knowledge of MMA that is required beyond what the Details section shows. Here is a step by step guide. **Step 1** : Go to the location of the folder using whatever file explorer you use on your computer. **Step 2**: Make a copy of that folder and put it somewhere else as a backup in case something goes wrong. **Step 3**: Copy the **location** of that folder (not the folder itself nor the name. The whole string/path for the folder). The location of that folder will be called home\docfolder in the following.

Comment: **Step 4** go on Mathematica and set a variable named folder, for example, to `folder="home\docfolder"`. **Step 5** : Look for all files with naturales in it using `notWanted=FileNames["*naturales*",folder]`. Check that the list is not empty and contains the files you expect. **Step 6**: Again please be careful and either save a backup of the folder or make a practice folder with  3 files. You can delete the entire list of files in `notWanted` by using `DeleteFile[notWanted]`.

Comment: You might also want to change the option for `IgnoreCase` depending on whether you want to treat uppercase and lowercase letters the same way or not.

Comment: Alternatively, you can save your notebook in the folder where you want to delete files. Make sure not to give the notebook a similar name to one you want to delete as the pattern matching might select the notebook. Then use `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]` to set the current directory as the directory the notebook is located in.

Comment: Then, you can omit using the name of the directory when using `FileNames` and use  `notWanted=FileNames["*naturales*"]` and then `DeleteFile[notWanted]`. If you do not want to check the content of the files in `notWanted`, not recommended, especially as a beginner,  then you can use directly  `DeleteFile[FileNames["*naturales*"]]`

Comment: Also yes as shown by the answer below you might have to use "\\" rather than "\" but Mathematica should ask whether you want to replace "\" with "\\" automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I might approach it.
I would make a list of directories to look in.

```
dirsToClean = {"C:\\Users\\rpotter\\Downloads", 
  "C:\\Users\\rpotter\\Documents", "C:\\Users\\rpotter\\Desktop"};
```

Then I would make a list of keywords.

```
keywords = {"test", "temp",".tmp"};
```

And add wildcards to either side of the keywords.

```
keywordsWC = "*" <> # <> "*" & /@ keywords
(*{"*test*", "*temp*", "*.tmp*"}*)
```

Now I can search for those files.

```
filesToDelete = FileNames[keywordsWC, dirsToClean, IgnoreCase -> True] (*Or False as desired*)
```

If everything looks good we can delete them.

```
DeleteFile[filesToDelete]
```

But maybe before deleting them we move them to a folder so we can look through them first.

```
CreateDirectory["c:\\FilesToDelete"]
RenameFile[#, 
   FileNameJoin[{"c:\\FilesToDelete", 
     FileNameSplit[#][[-1]]}]] & /@ filesToDelete
```

And then just delete all the files in that directory.

Comment: Hi, there might be a typo it should be `DeleteFile` rather than `FileDelete`. Also `keywords2` is not defined in the post.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed in above.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do something with the contribution of all of you,